# configuring appsettings.json for CIL appsettings

Tags: web8.5, cil

Has anyone tried using CIL appsetting strings in appsettings.json? I am writing a custom Web API in MVC6 for my client side MVC to pull content but got struck with this. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not sure CIL supports .NET Core/MVC 6 yet - you may want to double check this.

Comment: I am sure it doesn't support .NET Core yet. :-)